# Is there any difference between .NET 2 and .NET 4 assemblies running under .NET 4

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, .net-2.0

I maintain a .NET 2.0 library and recently it's users started asking for a .NET 4 version.

I could just duplicate existing project in Visual Studio, set `Target Framework` to `.NET Framework 4.0` and be done with it, but is there any difference between .NET 2 and .NET 4 assemblies running under .NET 4?

I mean, will it change anything if I just rebuild the same source code for .NET 4? Am I expected to have different set of unit test for .NET 2 and .NET 4 builds?

Comment: Yes, you didn't test it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.Net frameworks are [backward compatible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so .Net framework 2.0 library should work fine on .Net framework 4.0. I am not sure why your library users are asking for .Net framework 4.0 library, because it doesn't make any difference to them.

However if you want to recompile your .Net 2.0 library to 4.0 then normally there shouldn't be any issues but you should see: [Visual C# 2010 Breaking Changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855831%28VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: The Version Compatibility in the .NET Framework makes me think there _are_ differences.

Comment: @Bobrovsky, yes there are, Although these changes would rarely effect you during migration, but if they occur they could be real pain in the neck.